# Determine if a property is a native DOM property in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I am needing to distinguish between a "pure" JavaScript property on an object and one that is a native property like `innerHTML` or `style`.

In Safari I can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` and check the `configurable` property (which is false for special properties), however this unfortunately doesn't have the same results on Chrome or Firefox (which return that the properties are configurable).

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynCQy/1/) on different browsers to see the problem.

Is there a reliable way to determine if the property is a special internal property or not?

**Update**

I've noticed that Firefox actually returns `undefined` if you try to get the property descriptor of a native property, so that might work fine. That leaves Chrome, which unfortunately returns a property descriptor that looks exactly like a normal property.

For example, here's the descriptor for `innerHTML` in Chrome:

```
{"value":"","writable":true,"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
```

...and here for an empty string property called "test":

```
{"value":"","writable":true,"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
```

Exactly the same. :(

Comment: [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) seems to exist in Chrome 5+, FF 4+ and IE8+.

Comment: I don't think getOwnPropertyDescriptor is actually doing what you think it is. Its possible to set properties on any object to be non-configurable too. Are you actually trying to tell if a property on an object is a native property, i.e. one that is provided by the browser runtime?

Comment: Yes, but I don't care about explicitly unconfigurable properties. Primarily I need to tell if I can redefine a property without breaking the native handling of it.

Comment: I think, by "native" you mean "built-in", right? Also, what do you mean by "pure" JavaScript property?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas By "pure" I mean a property that simply stores a value and has no external effect (such as on the DOM).

Comment: @chaiguy Why would a DOM element have such a property? And how would it come about? Were it created by a JavaScript program?

Comment: Yeah I mean anyone can add their own property to a DOM object; I need to be able to distinguish between such a "user property" and a built-in native property that has its own native handling by the browser.

Comment: The getOwnPropertyDescriptor behavior in Firefox is required by the spec, but would also be the case for "expando" properties on the proto chain.  The Safari behavior of claiming the properties are not configurable is a bug.

Comment: Returning undefined for a property that clearly exists is the bug. If the spec says that then the spec is the problem. But the bigger problem is that it's not consistent across browsers. At this point I don't blame Safari because what they're doing makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the property is defined on a newly created instance of the DOM element in question:

```
'innerHTML' in (document.createElement('div')); //yes
```

A function that tests this might look like:

```
var test = function (elem, prop) {
    return prop in (typeof elem === 'string' ? document.createElement(elem) : elem)
}

console.log( test( 'div', 'innerHTML') );
console.log( test( document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'innerHTML') );
console.log( test( document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'monkey') );​
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is in the right direction. I was also thinking of checking to see if the property is defined on a known prototype like `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I see where you're going, but I really wish there were a way to do this without having to create an element just to perform the test. I expect this would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: If you find another way to do it, leave a comment here so I can read it in the future. In the mean time, I think this is as close as you are going to get. Creating elements in memory is very inexpensive. Unless you're doing this thousands of times in a loop or something, its not really that performance intensive.